# Why is this recursive Pascal procedure not being caught in an infinite loop?

Tags: recursion, infinite-loop, pascal

I wonder why the following recursive Pascal procedure actually terminates:

```
procedure reverseWordRecursive;

  var
  word : char;

begin
  read(word);
  if word = '.' then
    writeln
  else
    begin
      reverseWordRecursive;
      write(word)
    end;
end; {reverseWordRecursive}
```

The procedure acts differently as the code might suggest. When you run the code the call of `read(word)` only runs once in the beginning of the procedure. The user is not asked to input one single `char` at the beginning of each recursive call, but you rather input the whole `string` of `char`.

Why is it not being caught in an infinite loop at the "read(word)" call? Should it not ask the user to input a word for ever?

How does the procedure know to actually use the respective next character for each recursive call?

Comment: It keeps recursing until the input is a `.`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not clarify the strange behaviour of the procedure. I edited it now. Tom answered it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Read()` procedure, when used to read the standard input, stores all typed characters into a buffer including the entry terminating CR/LF (Enter).

The value returned by `Read()` is according to the type of the argument passed to `Read()`. For example, if the argument is a string, then all characters except the terminating CR/LF are returned (`ReadLn()` would return also CR/LF). If the variable is a `Char` then one character is returned, and the rest of the entered characters remain in the buffer, and can be read later by calling `Read()` again.

So, in your code, the read procedure reads standard input into a buffer until <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit.

Let's say you enter <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

At this point, since the parameter is a `char` the first entered character 'A' is returned to your code.

The char is evaluated, and if not '.' the procedure is called recursively. Now, there are chars in the input buffer, so the next character, 'B' is read from the buffer. The same for 'C' and then finally the '.'.

This terminates the recursive calls, and starts to unwind the stack, which happens in reversed order, C, B and A.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. This is first time I see this a quirk. :)

Answer (score 1):

When Pascal programs read from the standard input stream, they usually do not read single characters at a time, instead a line of characters is read and stored in a buffer, and characters are read from this buffer. This buffering happens automatically behind the scenes.

That is why the following program

```
program example(input);
var
   c : char;
begin
   writeln('Reading a character');
   read(c);
   writeln('The character read was ', c);
end.
```

will wait for you to enter a line of characters, even though it only reads one.